# Scanner - Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java

I have written a quite basic login system in Java. Theoretically speaking, everything should work and function properly. However, when I run the program and enter the username and password, it outputs an exception.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * A basic login system
 * @author Jamie <jamie@jamie.no>
 */
public class LoginSystem
{
    public static boolean isValidated = false;
    private static String userName = "";
    private static String password = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    runConsole();
    }

    public static void runConsole() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3 && !isValidated; i++) {
        System.out.println("You have entered the following username: ");
        userName = console.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You have entered the following password: ");
        password = console.nextLine();
        isValidated = AuthenticateUser(userName, password);
        }

        if (isValidated) {
        System.out.println("Access Granted. User is authenticated.");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Unauthorized Access.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * User authentication constructor
     * @param userName The username.
     * @param password The password.
     * @return true if user is validated.
     */
    public static boolean AuthenticateUser(String userName, String password) {
        return (userName.equalsIgnoreCase("User1") && password.equals("Pass1"));
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the exception msg:
[image]

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Code works fine in Eclipse, must be where you are running the program

Comment: Use `console.next()` , it deals with delimiter as well.

Comment: From what I can see it tells me nothing. But when I run the program, it throws an exception which states that no lines has been found. Would gladly appreciate it if you could help me debug further, as my PC is broken and due to that it's pretty difficult for me to debug over phone.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/V1njSm

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful console.next() gave me an error. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/faHkYQ

Comment: @AndroidGL - That screenshot corresponds to `console.nextLine()`, check the code in the image which you've executed!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful My apologies, a little bit tired here. It gave me an exception, although it is a little bit different from the last one: https://ibb.co/hx7PSk

Comment: Your code works good, I have not any problem

Comment: If the code functionality is good, then how come it's giving me this exception?

Comment: Have you closed the `Scanner` by mistake in the `for-loop`?

Comment: @Yahya I haven't closed the `Scanner` object. However, the only time I'm using the close() function is whenever I'm using the `BufferedReader` object.

Comment: Try to wrap each reading with `if(console.hasNextLine()){
          userName = console.nextLine();
        }` and `if(console.hasNextLine()){ password = console.nextLine();}`.

Comment: @Yahya That seemed to work, now I can finally see the messages if user failed authentication. However, I do have one last question - can you explain why the output lines are duplicated: https://ibb.co/eFD67k

Comment: If you have a new question ask a new question. And beyond that: don't use comments to provide more data, always update your question instead.

Comment: @GhostCat You probably haven't noticed yet, but since my PC is broken I have to use my phone. From what I can tell by looking at my recent comment, I don't see the `edit` button.

Comment: I am am using my mobile too. And I see that button. But yes, I have seen that to - sometimes that button is missing in the mobile view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `public class NoSuchElementException extends RuntimeException` Thrown
>   by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are
>   no more elements in the enumeration.

However, when I tried your code on **Eclipse**, it's running free of errors.
But when I tried it on [Code Playground](https://code.sololearn.com/#html), it gave me the same error.

```
You have entered the following username: 
You have entered the following password: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at LoginSystem.runConsole(LoginSystem.java:25)
    at LoginSystem.main(LoginSystem.java:11)
```

It seems it's a *bug* in their system. Because you need to input the `userName` and `password` for three loops in advance in one go at the very beginning of the run.
I went around this by wrapping the scan with `hasNextLine`which *Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.*

So, it becomes:

```
if(console.hasNextLine()){
   userName = console.nextLine();
}
if(console.hasNextLine()){
   password = console.nextLine();
}
```